# No executable code found at line x - when trying to debug

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, debugging, retrofit

I'm trying to debug a retrofit request function but everytime I run the debugger I get the error: ***No executable code found at line x.***
I've already tried all the solutions and read all the topics on this subject but couldn't find a proper solution for my problem.

This is my function and I'm getting the error on the **override fun lines (onFailure and onResponse)**. Those 2 functions (onFailure and onResponse) are not called at all and I'm getting the "cashCollectionData function has not been initialized" error but when I tried to debug I found the other problem with the No executable code..

```
lateinit var cashCollectionData: MutableList<CashCollection.CashCollectionItem>
    lateinit var financialDetailsData: MutableList<FinancialDetails.FinancialDetailsItem>
    lateinit var ticketDetailsData: MutableList<TicketDetails.TicketDetailsItem>

    fun getCashCollectionService(mandatorGuid: String): MutableList<CashCollection.CashCollectionItem> {
        val mandatorItem = MandatorItem(mandatorGuid)
        val guid: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
        guid["guid"] = mandatorItem.guid

        val call: Call<CashCollection> = createAPI().getCashCollection(mandatorItem.guid)
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<CashCollection> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<CashCollection>, response: Response<CashCollection>) {
                cashCollectionData = response.body()!!.data
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<CashCollection>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.i("TESTT", "Fail Cash Collection: " + t.localizedMessage)

            }
        })
        return cashCollectionData
    }
```

Please if you have any suggestion or solution tell me cause I couldn't find one yet. Thanks!

Comment: First thing I would try is Build -> Clean Project, and then Build -> Rebuild Project.

Comment: Already tried that... still not working

Comment: Do you use proguard rules for obfuscation? If yes, check if it is removing the required code form at the compilation.

Comment: I'm not sure but I dont think I use proguard rules for obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that Android Studio is conflicting on running an old build, since the build process can be incremental. Try doing `Build -> Clean Project` and then `Build -> Rebuild Project`.  If that doesn't sort it out, you might try `File -> Invalidate Caches | Restart`. Other than that, make sure you place your breakpoints in variable assignments or functions calls.

Comment: I tried both of these and still not working... I place a breakpoint on call.enqueue, on cashCollectionData assignment and on return..

Answer (score 1):

Also try to delete the app on the device. This worked for me.

Comment: Same. I had this issue using "Run 'app'" in Android Studio Hedgehog, and manually installing worked, I wish there was a way to prevent this Android Studio or gradle fu**ery.